# Understanding code from official tensorflow page

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, tensorflow2.0

I am confused about code on [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data).

question1)

Code block below shows output from that page. Before this step I dont see any code that trains our data using `model.fit` function. So what is the code below? Do they show predictions using random weights?

```
model.predict(train_features[:10])

array([[0.6296253 ],
       [0.82509124],
       [0.75135857],
       [0.73724824],
       [0.82174015],
       [0.33519754],
       [0.6719973 ],
       [0.30910844],
       [0.6378555 ],
       [0.8381703 ]], dtype=float32)

model = make_model(output_bias = initial_bias)
model.predict(train_features[:10])

array([[0.00124893],
       [0.00185736],
       [0.00164955],
       [0.00123761],
       [0.00137692],
       [0.00182851],
       [0.00170887],
       [0.00239349],
       [0.0024704 ],
       [0.00517672]], dtype=float32)


results = model.evaluate(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
print("Loss: {:0.4f}".format(results[0]))

Loss: 0.0157
```

question2)

Continuing on in the code it says below. What are `initial_weights`? are they random values?

```
initial_weights = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(),'initial_weights')
model.save_weights(initial_weights)
```

question3)

Then they say that

```
Before moving on, confirm quick that the careful bias initialization actually helped.Train the model for 20 epochs, with and without this careful initialization, and compare the losses:
```

, But I am not sure how they are assigning initial bias.
I understand we assign 0 bias for the object `zero_bias_history`. But how do we assign bias for `careful_bias_history`? isnt it supposed to have bias equal to `initial_bias`. How does `careful_bias_history` get the bias value? i felt that `careful_bias_history` should be created from a model that was created using `model = make_model(output_bias = initial_bias)`

```
### Confirm that the bias fix helps

Before moving on, confirm quick that the careful bias initialization actually helped.

Train the model for 20 epochs, with and without this careful initialization, and compare the losses: 

model = make_model()
model.load_weights(initial_weights)

model.layers[-1].bias.assign([0.0])
zero_bias_history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels), 
    verbose=0)

print (type(model))
#model.load_weights()

model = make_model()
model.load_weights(initial_weights)
careful_bias_history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels), 
    verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1: Yes, these predictions are from model after compiling but before training it.

Answer 2: Yes, they are random weights, for example, in Dense layer they are initialised using `glorot_uniform` . [tf.keras.layers.Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense#__init__)

Answer 3: The model we saved above had a bias initialised using `np.log([pos/neg])`, it is mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#optional_set_the_correct_initial_bias).

So, in `zero_bias_history`, they initialised bias with zeroes using `model.layers[-1].bias.assign([0.0])`, and in `careful_bias_history` they just loaded the saved model which already had the initialised bias.